# Contao CMS 3.5: Sender's name in subject and email as sender to reply

Tags: forms, email, variables, contao

How can I accomplish to have the sender's name in the subject of a contao (v.3.5.27) form and also when I receive that email I like to press reply in the mail program and be able to reply the sender.

There used to be the Extended Form Generator Plugin
https://de.contaowiki.org/EFG
But compatibility is only 3.2.2 - 3.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve that you simply need to have two form fields with the name `email` and `name`. Then Contao will add that automatically as the "reply to" address. See [system/modules/core/forms/Form.php#L374-L386](https://github.com/contao/core/blob/3.5.28/system/modules/core/forms/Form.php#L374-L386)